# What are the input variables of odefun when using the ode45 function?

Tags: matlab, ode

I am trying to solve a quite simple ODE (1. order reaction rates) with the function ode45, but while I am able to do that successfully, I am not 100% sure what is actually happening. This is the code for reference:

```
x0 = [0.1,0.1];
tspan = [0, 10];
k = [1, 1];

[t_a, x_a] = ode45(@odefun, tspan, x0, [], k);


plot(t_a, x_a)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('x')
legend('A','B')

function dxdt = odefun(t,x,k)
    k1  = k(1);
    dxdt = zeros(2,1);
    dxdt(1) = -2*k1*x(1)*x(1);
    dxdt(2) = k1*x(1)*x(1);
end
```

This yields the expected results, but what I do not understand is, what the input parameter of odefun actually are (I know what they represent, but not how they were created, as I never defined them). The documentation was no great help for that, so I am wondering, where are the coming from? Are they provided by ode45? If so how is that possible when odefun is an input of ode45?

Obviously this code is not fully written by me, so, to be more specific, I have trouble understanding how I know I have to use x(1).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about what `odefun` is.  It says "Functions to solve, specified as a function handle which defines the functions to be integrated."  As far as what `x(1)` is depends entirely on your function.

Comment: This code does not run.  Specifically `dxd` should be `dxdt`.  Also, the initial conditions have only one value yet your `odefun` is providing two outputs, meaning that you have a system of differential equations.  Please double check your post and update it with the correct code.

Comment: Sorry, I was sloppy when copying from the editor, I corrected it and made it hopefully more clear.

@Matt maybe I have some fundamental problem understanding what the function handel is doing (I am reading it up for some time now, but I don't think I fully grasped it in this specific context). But I still don't see where the inputs come from. Sorry, if this is stupid

Answer (score 0):

The `t` and `x` inputs are generated by ode45 based on the initial values of t and x which you provide. ode45 calls the function with new values of t and x as it solves the problem, with the new values being based on the output of your function.